# sharing template between frontend and backend (admin or adminhtml) in magento

Tags: magento, layout-xml

I wish to reuse a certain frontend UI element on the backend (under "design/adminhtml"). This would mostly consist of reusing the template (phtml). However, referencing the frontend layout handle from the backend would seem even better. Does magento provide a location for shared UI components, a way to declare them as shared, or a mechanism for referencing them across the frontend/adminhtml divide? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@coriscus
Yes that is possible. I found the trick you use frontend template from admin.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setData('area','frontend');
    $this->setTemplate('customer/online.phtml');
}
```

just set needed area in block constructor.

Comment: Thanks! This was valuable help: a lot of prior googling turned up nothing.

Comment: For what it's worth, for completeness, and for those, like myself, who are new to magento, this can be accomplished in layout-xml as  `<block... template="customer/online.phtml">
 <action method="setData">
  <key>area</key>
  <value>frontend</value>
 </action>
</block>`  or, more briefly, as  `<block... template="customer/online.phtml">
 <action method="setArea"><params>frontend</params></action>
</block>`  where *setArea('frontend')* does the same as *setData('area', 'frontend')*.

Comment: Be aware, that this method will use the same design package, as current admin package. In most of the cases it will be "default".