# magento - use a frontend template in adminhtml

Tags: php, magento

I have a order timeline page on frontend at :

```
/magento/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/sales/order/info.phtml
```

I am trying to use the same page on adminhtml, from `sales -> orders` on a single view order page I am creating a hyperlink on click of that I would like to show a popup that will display the timeline same as displayed on frontend page of info.phtml. Can I use the same template info.phtml I have in frontend or I have to create one more for backend? also any ideas how to approach this? thanks

I have created a black in

`magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml` and added the template code of info.phtml in timeline.phtml

```
    <adminhtml_sales_order_timeline>
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_timeline" name="timeline_tracking" template="sales/order/view/timeline.phtml"></block>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_timeline>
```

Edit :

The request is going to the controller :

```
 public function timelineAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

which loads the following layout :

```
    <adminhtml_sales_order_timeline>
                <remove name="header" />
                <remove name="footer" />

                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_timeline" name="sales_order_timeline" template="sales/order/timeline/timeline.phtml" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_timeline>
```

this removes the header and footer but this is not displaying the content of the template timeline.phtml, I have not done any other configurations for block, what am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755621/sharing-template-between-frontend-and-backend-admin-or-adminhtml-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

your Admin layouts will look for the phtmls inside adminhtml/ folder and not the frontend/ folders. What you can do is copy the info.phtml   inside your adminhtml/default/default/template/your_folder_name and include that in your adminhtml layout.