# Magento: adminhtml Block Directive Not Loading in frontend Email Template

Tags: magento, email-templates, transactional-email

I've been scouring the net in pursuit of this one. Magento Commerce comes us dry for me. grepping core code, reading Alan Storm, perusing Inchoo, and even finding related questions on SO turn up no answers for me.

With that said, **my problem is with a transactional email template that works when processed from the backend but *not* from the frontend**. Here's a snippet:

```
<td width="100%" colspan="2" align="left">

    <!-- inject products quote table -->
    {{block type="adminhtml/sales_quotation_email" template="sales/quotation/email_quote_items.phtml" inherits=$template quote=$quote salesrep=$salesrep}}

    <!-- inject cross-sell products table -->
    {{block type="adminhtml/sales_quotation_email" template="sales/quotation/email_quote_cross_sells.phtml" inherits=$template quote=$quote salesrep=$salesrep}}

</td>
```

In the backend, these blocks are rendered as expected. In the front-end, everything above and below these block directives is rendered, but it appears that the directives die in processing when it comes time to render the template. No errors are thrown.

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133435/magento-email-templates-blocks-not-rendering-from-adminhtml), but no luck. Originally I tried to use setDesignConfig on the email template model, but that didn't work. I even tried to set the `area` as an attribute in the directive, but that also did not work. A colleague suggested that I have two copies of the above templates: one set in `design/adminhtml` and the other `design/frontend`. I'd rather not have to worry about extra maintenance. Plus, I fear that I'd encounter the same problem if the block type specified in the directive comes from adminhtml. I don't want that solution.

So what am I doing wrong? What do I not understand?

How does Magento resolve the real path to the template, and is a template forced to reside in the area of its parent block?

Help is needed! Thanks.

Comment: +1. I'm a bit curious about this as well, as I haven't managed to find the time to figure this bit out. I know that adminhtml blocks should not be rendered in the front-end (due to ACL I presume). I've run into similar issues where the email store logo doesn't show when submitting orders from the backend (resolved by setting `_area=frontend` on the image directive). Is it possible that you will need to extend the block you want to render, and setting the store code/area conditionally based on where the email was called from?

Comment: @pspahn, thanks for the feedback. I was able to solve this in my case. Please see the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found a related post on [Magento Commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/9012/#t38947) that put me back on track. I started dumping out the design configuration in two controllers: 1 in `frontend` and one in `adminhtml`. I noticed immediately that theme information was missing in the `frontend` request. See some sample output from my `frontend` controller:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package Object (
    [_store:protected] => 
    [_area:protected] => frontend
    [_name:protected] => mypackage
    [_theme:protected] => Array
        (
            [layout] => 
            [template] => 
            [skin] => 
            [locale] => mytheme
        )

    [_rootDir:protected] => 
    [_callbackFileDir:protected] => 
    [_config:protected] => 
    [_shouldFallback:protected] => 1 )
```

Notice that `layout`, `template`, and `skin` are empty in the `theme` property. When I dumped the design configuration from an `adminhtml` controller, these properties were set.

So going back to my `frontend` controller, I added the following line before I instantiated my email template model:

---

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('adminhtml');
Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('mytheme');
```

---

And poof! It worked! My blocks directives were processed and the fully rendered content was returned as expected.

**So although my thinking was correct to set the `area`, that alone wasn't enough. I also has to configure the `theme`.**

I'm happy with the solution. I hope it helps others. <strike>But to fully answer this question, I'm still curious if anyone knows **why** package information is missing from the design configuration during a `frontend` request. Does it have to do with the block type in the directive coming from `adminhtml`? That would make sense, because `adminhtml` has no need to worry about theme information. I just don't know where those decisions would be made in core code.</strike> **See update below.**

**UPDATE:**

**Learned even more since the original post**. My question gave a code sample that built a block of a type that came from `adminhtml`. The path to the template, I *thought*, was resolving to the front-end, and that was why no template could be found. That wasn't actually the case. An adminhtml block, because of its class naming convention, will look in `design/adminhtml/package/default/module` for your template.

However, in my particular Magento installation, I have a design override in local.xml that changes the admin theme so that it admin requests check `design/adminhtml/package/mytheme/module` for templates. And that is where my phtml templates are stored. So on a front-end request, the controller has no clue about this override, and is only building up the design configuration based on what is set in the store configuration for the particular package and theme.

In summary, my call to setTheme() must utilize that modified config data, like so:

```
Mage::getDesign()->setTheme(
    (string)    Mage::app()
                ->getConfig()
                ->getNode('stores/admin/design/theme/default')
);
```

I guess that goes to say, then, that a simple call to setArea() would be sufficient for most installations.

Finally, you will need to revert the design configuration changes after your work is done, otherwise subsequent actions might produce undesired results.